# A question about an expression- "Payment has been effected"

Tags: expressions

In the prologue of the video game "Hitman 2" some priest gets kidnapped. 
In a note demanding ransom they leave behind, it says they will keep treating him
nicely until "payment has been effected".
I asked a few native speakers about this but they said they have never heard
this expression before.

I would like to know what exactly is that term.
Does it exist? What does it really mean?

Thank you,
Or

Comment: The normal way to say it is: payment has been made. It's poor writing but it may be done on purpose to show the ransomers are uneducated.

Answer (score 1):

***[Effect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/effect)*** is  commonly used an a noun, as a verb it is generally found in more formal contexts:

> - to produce as an effect; bring about; accomplish; make happen:
>     *The new machines finally effected the transition to computerized accounting last spring.*

As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=effect%20a%20payment%2C%20effect%20payments&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceffect%20a%20payment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffect%20payments%3B%2Cc0) the expressions "effect a payment/payments" meaning make a payment/payments are used  but are not common.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [*effect*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/effect): Cause
>   (something) to happen; bring about.

It means until payment has been made.